# Instagram - PHP API to post content

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

Does Instagram provide API support to authenticate and post content on user's account?

I have tried to google it out but could not get anything. Just want to re-confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

No they do not provide such API call.